# Is there something called quote_plus from request.compat?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to import quote_plus from requests.compat but they say cannot find reference in compat.pyi.
Is there a fix to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import [**`quote_plus(...)`**--(pydoc)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus) as

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
```